# fade in an bounce animation subview

Tags: xcode, swift

I have an subview that fades into the view. this goes perfectly with this code:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.9,  animations: {
            self.popUpView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()

})
```

But how can i make a sort of bounce? That the popupview fades in very hard and bounces a little bit back.

Comment: I agree with ABakerSmith. Most people are unaware that spring-with-damping animation can be used for a change of color or alpha - it does not have to be just physical position or size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `UIView`, you could use:

```
class func animateWithDuration(_ duration: NSTimeInterval,
                         delay delay: NSTimeInterval,
        usingSpringWithDamping dampingRatio: CGFloat,
         initialSpringVelocity velocity: CGFloat,
                       options options: UIViewAnimationOptions,
                    animations animations: () -> Void,
                    completion completion: ((Bool) -> Void)?)
```

To change the bounciness you'll want to change the `dampingRatio`; zero being the most bouncy and one being the least bouncy. From the [`UIView` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/animateWithDuration:delay:usingSpringWithDamping:initialSpringVelocity:options:animations:completion:):

> *Damping Ratio*: The damping ratio for the spring animation as it approaches its quiescent state.
>
> To smoothly decelerate the animation without oscillation, use a value
>   of 1. Employ a damping ratio closer to zero to increase oscillation.